# Lower specificity style being applied, instead of higher specificity hover

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, less, css-specificity

As you can see here:
[image: what?]

The selector `.wrapper-dropdown .label` is being applied, instead of the higher specificity `.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li div.liwrap:hover`

Why is that?
I'm using chrome on osx 10.8, if that's relevant

-edit

This [Less](http://lesscss.org/): http://hastebin.com/feyurojusa.avrasm
compiles to this css: http://hastebin.com/dihimuquju.css

And this [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/): http://hastebin.com/sipetaqigu.vhdl
Compiles to this html: http://hastebin.com/sufavolumo.xml

Addtionally I've got this small JavaScript handling click events: http://hastebin.com/sufavolumo.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element that is designated by `.label` is not the same element that is designated by `div.liwrap`; rather, `.label` is one of `div.liwrap`'s descendants. Specificity then becomes irrelevant, because the selectors are matching different elements altogether.

The strikethrough simply means that the `div.liwrap` ancestor's `color` is being canceled out instead of being inherited because you're giving `.label` its own `color` declaration.

If you want `.label` to inherit from `div.liwrap` on hover, you need to modify the following rule in your LESS code:

```
  .dropdown li div.liwrap:hover {
    border-color: #00aeef;
    color: #00aeef;
  }
```

To something like this:

```
  .dropdown li div.liwrap:hover {
    border-color: #00aeef;
    color: #00aeef;
    .label {
      color: #00aeef; // Or color: inherit;
    }
  }
```